# Installiation of new apk file programatically shows error

Tags: android

I have placed a conditional checking in the oncreate of my application for checking the version update.If New version of my application available I will call the onDestroy.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(“true”.equal(CheckVersion))
    {
        alertbox.setMessage("Do you want to update Aplication with Latest version?");
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                try {

                    onDestroy();
                } catch (Exception exception) {

                    exception.toString();
                }                       

            }
        });
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                LaunchManifest();
            }
        });
        alertbox.show();
    }
}

/*
 * In the onDestroy method I have Placed the code for downloading the New
 * apk file and installation of the apk file methods as given below
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    DownloadOnSDcard();
    InstallApplication();
}

public void DownloadOnSDcard() {
    try {

        urlpath = "http://192.168.1.158/VisionEPODWebService/VisionEPOD.apk";
        String ApkName = "VisionEPOD.apk";

        URL url = new URL(urlpath.toString());
        // Your given URL.
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();
        // Connection Complete here.!
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // "HttpURLConnection complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
        File file = new File(PATH); // PATH = /mnt/sdcard/download/
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File outputFile = new File(file, ApkName.toString());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card Path: " +
        // outputFile.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
        // Get from Server and Catch In Input Stream Object.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1); // Write In FileOutputStream.
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
        // till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in
        // download file.
        // So plz Check in DDMS tab and Select your Emualtor.
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // "Download Complete on SD Card.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // download the APK to sdcard then fire the Intent.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }
}

public void InstallApplication() {
    String ApkName = "VisionEPOD.apk";
    String PackageName = "com.Vision.EPOD";
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse(PackageName.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"
                    + ApkName.toString())), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is that when my method for installation is got executed it shows an alert box

Replace application
The application you are installing will replace another application. All previous user data will be saved.
And have OK and Cancel button

When I clicked ok button it show another button for installation of the application

But when I clicked the Installation button the application shows a progress bar showing installing

Then after that I will got a message application not installed with done button.

ie My new updates not got installed.

Is it the right way I have implemented the version update procedure. Will any one review please.Sorry for the lengthy code.

Comment: Please have a look at the logcat output. There should be an error message there too. If you post this message we maybe can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that you first install the application on your device from Eclipse. Doing this will sign your app with one certificate.

Then you have your .apk-file placed at some location - to make this .apk-file you had to sign it with a certificate.

The certificate that Eclipse signed your app with is not the same as the one you signed your .apk-file with - meaning when you download the .apk-file and try to install it, there will be a certificate mismatch and it won't install.

What you could do is:

1. Install the app via the .apk-file on your device
2. Create a newer version of the .apk-file and place it on the web.
3. Run the app on the device and the update should succeed.